# Cakephp 3.4 red velvet

Tags: cakephp-3.4

I want to know about the cakephp 3.4 request cycle whether it is change or not according to previous versions of cakephp and please help me to understand cakephp request cycle easily.

Comment: Better refer to cakephp cookbook

Comment: Or the [changelogs](https://cakephp.org/changelogs)...